# Invalid conversion from runtime

Tags: apex, callout

System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map, can anyone suggest what should be the type???

```
public with sharing class blocxHeroController{
public map<String, Object> getHeroDetails(String strEndPointURL){

map<String, Object> mapJsonData = new map<String, Object>();
String strResponse = null;
if(String.isNotBlank(strEndPointURL)) {
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  
httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://api.myjson.com/bins/xfx0i');
httpRequest.setMethod('GET');   
try {  
    Http http = new Http();   
    HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);  

    while(httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 302) {
        // httpRequest.setEndpoint(httpResponse.getHeader('Location'));
        httpResponse = new Http().send(httpRequest);
    }
    if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
        strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();  
    } 
    else {  
        throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());  
    }   
} 
catch(Exception ex) {  
    throw ex;  
}  
} 
if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
mapJsonData = (map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
System.debug('mapJsonData ===> '+ mapJsonData);
}
if(!mapJsonData.isEmpty()) {
return mapJsonData;
}
else {
return null;
}
}
}
```

Comment: In which line you have error ?

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/xfx0i returns an array objects, while map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse); tries to cast that to a Map<String, Object>

Comment: @kurunve An answer would have been more appropriate than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As defined in the endpoint (https://api.myjson.com/bins/xfx0i), returned data does look like following:

```
[
    {
        "altText": "sample",
        "description": "sample",
        "header": "sample",
        "href": "#",
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "altText": "Second card accessible description.",
        "description": "Third Slide description",
        "header": "Third Slide",
        "href": "#",
        "id": 2,
        "image": "sample"
    }
]
```

In order to process it properly, it is necessary to cast that to an array of objects first:

```
List<Object> json_array_data;
if(!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
    json_array_data = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
    System.debug('json_array_data ===> '+ json_array_data);
}
```

After that, each entry of the array can be casted to `Map<String, Object>` and processed one by one.

Comment: i'm not clear can you brief me please???@kurunve